# Why would HTTP transfer via wget be faster than lftp/pget?

Tags: http, ftp, download, wget

I'm building software that needs to do massive amounts of file transfer via both HTTP and FTP. Often times, I get faster HTTP download with a multi-connection download accelerator like axel or lftp with pget. In some cases, I've seen 2x-3x faster file transfer using something like:

```
axel http://example.com/somefile
```

or

```
lftp -e 'pget -n 5 http://example.com/somefile;quit'
```

vs. just using wget:

```
wget http://example.com/somefile
```

But other times, wget is significantly faster than lftp. Strangly, this is even true even when I do lftp with get, like so:

```
lftp -e 'pget -n 1 http://example.com/somefile;quit'
```

I understand that downloading a file via multiple connections won't always result in a speedup, depending on how bandwidth is constrained. But: why would it be slower? Especially when calling lftp/pget with -n 1?

Comment: This should probably be on http://superuser.com

Comment: Your software shouldn't be shelling to the command line. Use curl, it has wrappers for most major languages.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock - Out of curiosity, why not? I often find it better to use child processes instead of adding a bunch of library code to my application.  It has benefits as well as drawbacks imho.

Comment: @jondahl IMHO You don't get as fine a level of control. When something fails you have to parse a string. You have to worry about installing the external application with an installer. With a library you can effectively do the multi-threading yourself which is better sometimes. Using a external app is more convenient to develop, but it can be a headache out in the wild.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @Byron Whitlock, I used libcurl wrapped in Ruby for this, but got intermittent timeouts writing to files on 3GB downloads. These tools are pretty well optimized and reliable at the command line level. That, plus the possibility of accelerated downloads, led me to lftp.

Comment: My understanding is that lftp supports http, so aren't all these transfers using http protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the HTTP server is compressing the stream using gzip?  I can't remember if wget handles gzip [Content Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.5) or not.  If it does, then this might explain the performance boost.  Another possibility is that there is an HTTP cache somewhere in the pipeline. You can try something like

```
wget --no-cache --header="Accept-Encoding: identity"
```

and compare this to your FTP-based transfer times.

Comment: Not to mention things like content distribution networks, QOS routing (particularly in relation to non-passive ftp), proxy caching.....